# Finite limit of $f/g$ at infinity implies integrable

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,g : [a,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f/g$ has finite limit at $\infty$.

If either $f$ or $g$ is Lebesgue-integrable then why must the other be also?

I know I have to use the comparison test but I’m not sure how.

Comment: Hint: If $\lim f/g=c$ then $\lim |f|/|g|=|c|$.

Comment: Also, a limit of zero needs some care.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich can you then flip the fraction around to get a limit for $g/f$. Is that legal?

Comment: @copper.hat So is it only true for non zero limit?

Comment: @Gabi23 : If $g$ is everywhere $0$ and $f$ is everywhere $1,$ then $\lim\limits_{+\infty} (g/f) = 0$ but $\displaystyle \int\limits_{[a,+\infty)} |f(x)| \, dx = +\infty. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

$a=1, f(x)=\frac 1 {x^{2}}, g(x) =\frac 1 x$ is a counter-example. However, if the limit of $\frac f g$ is finite and nonzero then the conclusion holds.

Comment: Maybe "finite" in this context means in the open interval $(0,+\infty). \qquad$

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. I am saying that the statement is false when $a=1$. Behavior near $0$ has nothing to do with it.  Besides OP clearly says finite limit at $\infty$. @MichaelHardy

Comment: It was assumed that the limit is finite. If "finite" is taken to imply non-zero, then your counterexample doesn't work. I wouldn't use the word "finite" that was without saying that that's what I meant, but I think it could happen.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Makes no sense at all to say that $0$ is not finite.

Comment: One sometimes speaks of infinite products "diverging to zero" (I assume that's because $0,$ like $+\infty,$ is an absorbing element for multiplication by positive numbers. And I've seen "finite" being construed as "nonzero" in some contexts.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{x\,\to\,+\infty} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)} = L \in (0,+\infty)$ and $\displaystyle\int\limits_{[a,+\infty)} |g(x)|\,dx <+\infty.$ Then for some positive number $b$ you have $0 < f(x) < (L+1)g(x)$ whenever $x>b.$ Therefore

$$
\int\limits_{[a,+\infty)} |f(x)|\,dx \le \int\limits_{[a,+\infty)} (L+1)|g(x)|\,dx < +\infty.
$$

Since we assumed $L\ne0$ above, you can apply the same argument with $g/f$ in place of $f/g$ and $1/L$ in place of $L.$ But that doesn't work if $L=0.$

But what if $x\not>b\text{ ?}$ We can't say what happens if $a<x\le b.$